# Grunt "reference error" and "task not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am actually configuring grunt with qunit to run unit tests with jenkins (following this tutorial: http://shashikantjagtap.net/javascript-continuous-integration-jenkins-qunit-grunt/) but I am actually blocked by this error:

> > ReferenceError: gruntConfig is not defined
> >     Warning: Task "qunit_junit" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

my devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.6",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-parallel-behat": "*",
    "grunt-qunit-cov": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-qunit-istanbul": "*",
    "grunt-qunit-junit": "^0.1.1",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.6",
    "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
    "gulp-apidoc": "^0.2.3",
    "gulp-documentation": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-istanbul": "^0.10.3",
    "gulp-jscs": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.4",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "should": "^8.3.0",
    "supertest": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

and my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['qunit_junit', 'qunit']);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-qunit-istanbul');
    gruntConfig.qunit = {
    src: ['static/test/index.html'],
    options: {
        coverage: {
        src: ['static/js/**/*.js'],
        instrumentedFiles: 'temp/',
        htmlReport: 'report/coverage',
        coberturaReport: 'report/',
        linesThresholdPct: 20
        }
    }
    };
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-qunit-junit');
    gruntConfig.qunit_junit = {
    options: {
        dest: 'report/'
    }
    };
}
```

Anyone encountered this error or have an idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: Why are you using gulp **and** grunt?

Comment: Do you mean grunt.config?

Comment: I am using only grunt and I speak about the Gruntfile.js, sorry for the imprecision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the `ReferenceError`: you have not defined the `gruntConfig` object. Add `var gruntConfig = {};` to define the object.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
   grunt.registerTask('default', ['qunit_junit', 'qunit']);
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-qunit-istanbul');

   //Add the below line to defined the object.
   var gruntConfig = {};
   gruntConfig.qunit = { ... }

   //code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the sample Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

};
```

1. Configure the tasks
2. Load the tasks
3. register the tasks